# I'm trying to reference another variable in another script. Why does it say that the name 'reference' does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, reference, unity-game-engine

So I have a script named points, and in it I have this:

```
public static float points;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    points = 0;
}
```

This exists as a way to know how many points you earned from collecting a certain object. Each of those objects has a script attached that says this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        reference.GetComponent(Points).points =+ 1;
    }
}
```

My friend told me this should allow me to reference the points variable in the Points script from this script, but Unity tells me the name 'reference' doesn't exist in the current context. I don't understand how to fix this, so if anybody could help me out, I would appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 2):

Few things here, firstly, not sure if you intend for `points` to be `static`. This means that the `points` value will be *shared* among *all* `Points` components on *all* GameObjects.

Now, depending on whether or not you intend to keep `points` static or not will determine how you access/change the value.

---

If you do not intend it to be shared, you need to make an instance-level field:

```
public float points;

void Start () 
{
    points = 0;
}
```

Secondly, the way you retrieve other components using `GetComponent` in C# is a bit different than the JavaScript/UnityScript version: (I'm assuming from your code, the name of the component script is `Points`)

```
GetComponent<Points>().points =+ 1;
```

See this Unity doc page for more information on generics and how to use this method: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/GenericFunctions.html

---

However, if you did intend `points` to be shared (some refer to it as "global"), then keep it static and you don't need to bother pulling out a component reference or initialize it on `Start` or treat it as a component/MonoBehaviour:

```
public static class Points
{
     public static float points = 0;
}
```

Then your updating code would be:

```
if(other.tag == "Player")
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Points.points =+ 1;
}
```

---

EDIT: Also, I just noticed you have a pretty significant possible typo in your code. You have

```
reference.GetComponent(Points).points =+ 1;
```

Notice the `=+`. This is the same as writing:

```
reference.GetComponent(Points).points = +1;
```

This means you will always be assigning it the fixed/constant value of positive 1. But given your spacing, it *looks* like you might have intended to *increment* the value by 1 rather than assign it to 1. If so, rewrite it to be:

```
reference.GetComponent(Points).points += 1; //notice the += instead of =+
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `reference`, not `points`.

No reference to `reference` (no pun intended) has been provided.